# Auto selected delimiter while using csv-serde

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-serde, hiveddl

Have created a table using:

```
 )   
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties(
"field.delim"="|"
)
```

When I tried to upload a file, that is comma-delimited, it has been uploaded correctly. How is it possible, if I had configured pipe as a delimiter for the data? Does csv-Serde has some "smart" way of identifying the delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) valid CSVSerde properties are

```
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "'",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
```

Default separator, quote, and escape characters if unspecified

```
DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER \
DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER  "
DEFAULT_SEPARATOR        ,
```

`field.delim` is not supported property which is ignored and it uses default setting.
This property is valid for another SerDe [MultiDelimitSerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe)

Comment: Thank you a lot! will change to MultiDelimitSerDe